# SSL Handshake Failure When Connecting to MongoDB Atlas from Python

Tags: python, mongodb, handshake

I'm using the pymongo library to connect to MongoDB Atlas with the following Python code snippet:

I have tried changing my network environment and confirmed my Atlas cluster is operational with no ongoing maintenance that could affect connectivity. Below is the Python code snippet I'm using to establish the connection:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, server_api
import certifi

# MongoDB Atlas connection URI
uri = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-address>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=TaipeiYouBikeHourlyData'

# Use the certifi library to get the path of the CA certificate
ca = certifi.where()

try:
    # Create a MongoClient instance and specify the CA certificate path
    client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=server_api.ServerApi('1'), tlsCAFile=ca)
    
    # Send a ping command to test the connection
    response = client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Successfully connected to MongoDB, response:", response)

except Exception as e:
    print("Error connecting to MongoDB:", e)
```

I've already tried switching networks, confirming my MongoDB Atlas cluster's status, and ensuring my Python environment uses the latest versions of necessary libraries. However, the issue persists.

Question:

Has anyone encountered similar SSL handshake failures with MongoDB Atlas, and how were you able to resolve it? Any suggestions on troubleshooting steps or configurations I might be missing?

Comment: Please edit the formatting of your question. It is not rendering correctly, making it hard to read. Also, please add the missing code snippet mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: I am not familiar with python, what is the output of `ca`?` Maybe try to put it in the connection string uri, instead of a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Verify it is a `tlsCAFile` issue or if it is network related. TLS/SSL runs over a transport protocol, such as TCP. Disable the TLS and verify if the connection is established:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=server_api, tlsContext=sslContext)
```

If there is no connection failure now, then your issue appears to incorrect credentials. If credentials are correct and you have the latest version of certifi, then I would check your firewall. MongoDB Atlas runs on AWS and therefore sits inside a VPC. The VPC can have public or private subnets. Even if it is on a public subnet, is the security group open? can you ping 27017?

There are various causes to this error but do process of elimination.

Comment: In general your answer goes in the right direction but it has a few errors: You can connect to a MongoDB without valid credentials (but in such case, you are not authenticated to execute any command). What is a "private subnet"? Private IP's are not routed over the internet, thus you can never reach a host over the internet by it's private IP. MongoDB Atlas are not always hosted on AWS, you can also order MS Azure or GCP. `ping` does not use TCP port 27017, it is a completely different protocol. Reaching a host by `ping` does not mean, you can reach it also by any TCP port.

Comment: I reopened my project by choosing Google Cloud Platform instead of AWS, and now I can connect to my MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issues I'm facing are tied to the WiFi network I'm using. The code runs flawlessly at school, but I encounter errors when I try to run it using my home WiFi. Below is the code snippet in question:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
client = MongoClient(uri, tls=True, tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```

```
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Connection to MongoDB failed: {e}")

databases = client.list_database_names()
print("Databases:", databases)
```

Despite attempting to establish a connection with these settings, I am unable to successfully ping MongoDB from my home network.

The problem may be related to my home WiFi configuration or network restrictions that differ from those at my school, affecting the SSL handshake or the connection to MongoDB.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).