# SSL Handshake Failure While Connecting to MongoDB Atlas from Python

Tags: python, mongodb, handshake

I'm attempting to connect to my MongoDB Atlas cluster from a Python application but am encountering an SSL handshake failure error. I've verified my MongoDB Atlas URI is correct and have tried several solutions without success.

**Error Message:**

```
Error connecting to MongoDB: SSL handshake failed: ac-efw9wvu-shard-00-02.ubua0y2.mongodb.net:27017: [('SSL routines', '', 'tlsv1 alert internal error')] (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-efw9wvu-shard-00-00.ubua0y2.mongodb.net:27017: [('SSL routines', '', 'tlsv1 alert internal error')] (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-efw9wvu-shard-00-01.ubua0y2.mongodb.net:27017: [('SSL routines', '', 'tlsv1 alert internal error')] (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65e4
```

**Details:**

I'm using the `pymongo` library to connect to MongoDB Atlas with the following Python code snippet:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient, server_api
import certifi

# MongoDB Atlas connection URI
uri = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-address>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=TaipeiYouBikeHourlyData'

# Use the certifi library to get the path of the CA certificate
ca = certifi.where()

try:
    # Create a MongoClient instance and specify the CA certificate path
    client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=server_api.ServerApi('1'), tlsCAFile=ca)
    
    # Send a ping command to test the connection
    response = client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Successfully connected to MongoDB, response:", response)

except Exception as e:
    print("Error connecting to MongoDB:", e)
```

**Question:**

Has anyone encountered similar SSL handshake failures with MongoDB Atlas, and how were you able to resolve it? Any suggestions on troubleshooting steps or configurations I might be missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL Handshake Failure When Connecting to MongoDB Atlas from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78098069/ssl-handshake-failure-when-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-from-python)

Comment: Take a look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/faq/security/#what-versions-of-tls-does-service-support- and make sure the local Python can support the same version.  If this is not a free tier, you should be able to download the log to get more detail.  If this is a free tier, contact Atlas support to get more details about the failure.